# How to reload form without closing it?Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, forms

I need to make my form reloads after certain events. Actually what I want is to run code that in load event handler. This can be done by simply hiding this and opening new form, but this causes other problems, like application never stop debugging, cause forms aren't closed.

```
Me.Hide()
Dim oForm As Aplikacija
oForm = New Aplikacija()
oForm.Show()
```

I also tried with Me.Refresh() but it doesn't solve problem.
Does anyone have idea how to solve this?

Comment: Move code from load event handler to new method. Invoke new method from load event handler and from wherever else you want to trigger the "load" behaviour?

Comment: Did it with Aplikacija_Load(Me, New System.EventArgs).